# Unix Command to List files containing string but *NOT* containing another string

Tags: linux, command-line, find, command, grep

How do I recursively view a list of files that has one string and specifically doesn't have another string? Also, I mean to evaluate the text of the files, not the filenames.

---

Conclusion:

As per comments, I ended up using:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec grep -lR 'base\-maps' {} \; | xargs grep -L 'base\-maps\-bot'
```

This returned files with "base-maps" and not "base-maps-bot". Thank you!!

Comment: Easiest way is using `grep -l` to list files matching a pattern, then pipe that to `grep -v`.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Mikel: However, it will pipe only the file names to the other `grep` which in turn can only filter from those file names and not file contents.

Comment: I've tried that, and agree with Alan that it only filters filenames. Thus, it doesn't accomplish what I hope.

Comment: @Alan Can't you pass grep a fileset, and if so, can't you pass in a fileset based on another grep? This is just me imagining possibilities, but if anyone knew how to do it, that'd be awesome :D

Comment: Matrym: Something similar to `ls -1 *.html | xargs grep -l '<foo>' - | xargs grep -L '<bar>' -` can be done as has been stated by [Sander Marechal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989519/unix-command-to-list-files-containing-string-but-not-containing-another-string/4989577#4989577).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -rl <string-to-match> | xargs grep -L <string-not-to-match>
```

Explanation: `grep -lr` makes grep recursively (r) output a list (l) of all files that contain `<string-to-match>`. xargs loops over these files, calling `grep -L` on each one of them. `grep -L` will only output the filename when the file does not contain `<string-not-to-match>`.

Comment: Should the grep strings be quotationed or escaped? Yes and no.

Comment: Also, is there a good way to make the process more efficient by only including .html files?

Comment: @Matrym `find . -name "*.html" -exec grep -l <string-to-match> {} \; | xargs grep -L <string-not-to-match>`

Comment: @chrisaycock adding R and escaping hyphens, does this look right?  find . -name "*.html" -exec grep -lR 'base\-maps' {} \; | xargs grep -L 'base\-maps\-bot'

Comment: Fantastic. Awesome awesome awesome.

Comment: @Matrym Don't use `-R` with `find` as it is already recursive. Only use `-R` if `grep` is used by itself.

Comment: you can make the process more efficient by using ack-grep for the first command: ack-grep -al <string-to-match> or in your case ack-grep --html -l <string-to-match>

Answer (score 3):

The use of xargs in the answers above is not necessary; you can achieve the same thing like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q <string-to-match> {} \; -not -exec grep -q <string-not-to-match> {} \; -print
```

`grep -q` means run quietly but return an exit code indicating whether a match was found; `find` can then use that exit code to determine whether to keep executing the rest of its options.  If `-exec grep -q <string-to-match> {} \;` returns 0, then it will go on to execute `-not -exec grep -q <string-not-to-match>{} \;`.  If that also returns 0, it will go on to execute `-print`, which prints the name of the file.

As another answer has noted, using `find` in this way has major advantages over `grep -Rl` where you only want to search files of a certain type.  If, on the other hand, you really want to search all files, `grep -Rl` is probably quicker, as it uses one `grep` process to perform the first filter for all files, instead of a separate `grep` process for each file.

Answer (score 1):

These answers seem off as the match *BOTH* strings. The following command should work better:

```
grep -l <string-to-match> * | xargs grep -c <string-not-to-match> | grep '\:0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic construction:

```
find . -name <nameFilter> -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Z -l <patternYes> | xargs -0 grep -L <patternNo>
```

This command outputs files whose name matches `<nameFilter>` (adjust `find` predicates as you need) which contain `<patternYes>`, but do not contain `<patternNo>`.

The enhancements are:

- It works with filenames containing whitespace.
- It lets you filter files by name.

If you don't need to filter by name (one often wants to consider all the files in current directory), you can strip `find` and add `-R` to the first `grep`:

```
grep -R -Z -l <patternYes> | xargs -0 grep -L <patternNo>
```

Answer (score 0):

find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec grep -L "string-not-to-match" {} \;

This Command will get all ".py" files that don't contain "string-not-to-match" at same directory.

Answer (score 0):

To match string A and exclude strings B & C being present in the same line I use, and quotes to allow search string to contain a space

```
grep -r <string A> | grep -v -e <string B> -e "<string C>" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

Explanation: grep -r recursively filters all lines matching  in output format

> filename: line

To exclude (grep -v) from those lines the ones that also contain either -e string B or -e string C. awk is used to print only the first field (the filename) using the colon as fieldseparator -F

Comment: Please add a little explanation for your code for further information.